# IOS about weak and strong, what's the result should be? and constant declare

Tags: ios, weak-references, strong-references

there are two properties like below

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Contact : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong)NSDate *birthDay;
@property(nonatomic, weak)NSDate *birthDay1;

- (void)testWeakProperty;

@end
```

on implementation file as：

```
- (void)testWeakProperty {
    self.birthDay = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
    self.birthDay1 = self.birthDay;
    self.birthDay = nil;
    NSLog(@"_birthday1 is %@, %@", self.birthDay1 , self.birthDay);
}
```

why the result is not `_birthday1` is `(null), (null)`?

I found that 
[iOS ARC - weak and strong properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452822/ios-arc-weak-and-strong-properties).
if `self.birthDay` is constant, it will not be deallocated. but there is `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]`,

now I want to know if the return value is constant and how to verify declare result is constant and a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is that you're dealing with an autorelease object. If a method name starts with `init`, `copy`, `mutableCopy` or `new`, you'll receive a non-autorelease object. This is not the case here (you are using `dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow`) and as a result, you'll receive an autorelease object.

Thus, you are instantiating an autorelease object and therefore it will not be deallocated until the autorelease pool is drained. And your weak reference will not be `nil`-ed until the object is deallocated. The deallocation of autorelease objects happens when your app yields back to the run loop (or you explicitly create your own autorelease pool).

This not a question of the object being "a constant". And that other question you reference is discussing `NSString` which, being heavily optimized, does not conform to traditional object memory management rules.

You can change the behavior by explicitly adding your own autorelease pool, which will cause the object to be deallocated when the pool is drained at the end of the `@autoreleasepool` block, and you'll see your `(null), (null)` response:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    self.birthDay = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
    self.birthDay1 = self.birthDay;
    self.birthDay = nil;
}
NSLog(@"_birthday1 is %@, %@", self.birthDay1 , self.birthDay);
```

You can also use a non-autorelease object (e.g. use a method whose name starts with `init`) and this non-autorelease object will be deallocated immediately after being set to `nil`:

```
self.birthDay = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
self.birthDay1 = self.birthDay;
self.birthDay = nil;
NSLog(@"_birthday1 is %@, %@", self.birthDay1 , self.birthDay);
```

This will also show you `(null), (null)`.

Answer (score 0):

As Rob explaining, the important point is the fact you are using an auto-released object.

Just a small precision about his explanation, `[NSDate date...]` is in fact a short (*convenience*) version of :

```
[[[NSDate alloc] initWith...] autorelease]
```

Which behave differently than an non-autoreleased instance:

```
[[NSDate alloc] initWith...]
```

Comment: Thanks your quickly reply.

Comment: you're welcome, but on stackoverflow to thank someone, you upvote/approve their answer ;)

Comment: sorry, i can' vote you answer, because of my reputation is below 15 .when i test use NSString like below: On .h file i declare a variable `@property(weak)NSString *address;` in implementation file i write below method `- (void)testWeakString {
    NSString *rawString = @"Hello, ";
    NSString *resultString = [rawString stringByAppendingString:@"World"];
    self.address = resultString;
    resultString = nil;
    NSLog(@"what's is my address: %@", self.address);
} ` the result is  **what's is my address: (null)**, is there any different.

Comment: Weird I would expect an error there, since self.address reference a deallocated address.

Comment: yeah, because the property is weak, when address is deallocated, self.address will be nil. this is weak feature